# Python / Tkinter Grid - Placing PNG Labels below Entry boxes

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Here's the code I am using (one example):

```
import os
import win32api
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#...
def mainloop():

    root = Tk()
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
#...
    pillarImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pillars.png"))
    pillars_label = ttk.Label(root)
    pillars_label['image'] = pillarImg
#...
    rldir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=40, textvariable=rldir)
    pillars_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=10, textvariable=Pillars)
#...
    rldir_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5, sticky=(W,E))
    pillars_label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    pillars_entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
#...
    root.mainloop()

mainloop()
```

This code results in the two entry boxes being above the image, even though I set the grid to have the image between the two entry boxes...?

Here's a pic of what I mean:
[image: app-screenshot]

Comment: Link to the image, didn't seem to work to link it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnbfoBHKQzZP6MuaMoogwOjkxFdSTC-O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The label is not inside `mainframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I just figured it out.

here:

```
pillars_label = ttk.Label(root)
```

I added the label to root.

While here:

```
rldir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=40, textvariable=rldir)
```

the entry boxes are in the mainframe. lol.

Comment: not sure why the code didn't post in the 2nd box, i meant the line with the entry,     rldir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=40, textvariable=rldir)